# Azure ARM Deploy DNS Entries

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am looking for a way to create DNS CNAME entries in Azure DNS via Azure Resource Manager Templates but unable to find a way/the syntax for it.

In the samples project here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates they only demo how to create a DNS zone but not the individual A/CNAME records.

Can someone please share the ARM template code on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an individual cname record:

```
{
    "name": "[concat('domain.com/cname_record_name)]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME",
    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
    "properties": {
        "TTL": 60,
        "CNAMERecord": {
            "cname": "what.it.targets"
        }
    }
}
```

domain.com - should be the name of the dns zone you are targeting. cname should be the value you point your cname at.